# http post method problem

Tags: android

In my application I'm using outpost method to send data to web service which is in .net.Now when i send string with spaces or special characters it takes the string with e.g. test string would display like test+string.

I'm using httpDefaultClient with nameValuePair to send data...i've used UrlEncode function to encode my string but still result is the same...
Please help me...

Here is my code

```
//web service call
                HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
                request.setURI(new URI(url2));

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                //  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CreateHotSpots", value))
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sKey",""+globalClass.getUser_key()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sLAKE",encodedlakename));
                if(!(DragAndDropPinActivity.point.isEmpty())){
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sLAT",""+DragAndDropPinActivity.point.get(0)));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sLon",""+DragAndDropPinActivity.point.get(1)));

                }
                else
                {
                    url2=url2.concat("&sLAT="+""+myLatitude);
                    url2=url2.concat("&sLon="+""+myLongitude);

                }

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sDesc",encodedDesc));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sSpeciesofFish",encodedFishSpecies));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sBaitUsed",encodedbUsed));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sWeatherInformation",encodedwInfo));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("season",encodedlseason));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sDesc",""+encodedDesc));
                if(share)
                {
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sShareInfo","true"));
                }
                else
                {
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sShareInfo","false"));
                }

                Log.e("name value pairs",""+nameValuePairs.toString());
                UrlEncodedFormEntity entity_st=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8");
                request.setEntity(entity_st);

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
                if (resEntity != null) { 

                    Responce=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                    Log.i("responce ======",""+Responce);

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                String message=e.getMessage();
                Log.e("meaasge with erroe",message);
            }

            return Responce;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***step 1***

You have specified a "UTF-8" encoding in

```
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity_st=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8");
```

Try to change it to

```
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity_st=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
```

---

***step 2***

I noticed that the strings you are adding to the request are called `encodeXXXX`

Does this mean that you are encoding them before adding them to the ValuePairs?

If so, stop doing this and keep them as normal strings.

Comment: @android why are your variables called `encodedxxxxx`? Are you doing any kind of encoding?

Comment: user may add special characters so i was using URLEncoder function...do i need to remove that?